# FFMPEG concat ONE intro video to MANY file in directory - all mp4

Tags: linux, bash, ffmpeg

I'm trying to write a concatenation script (windows) to add an intro.mp4 video to over a hundred other mp4 videos in a directory.

The codec will stay the same mp4, the intro filename will stay the same, but the main video names will change, but all are in the same directory.

I've started writing the bash script

```
#!/bin/bash
for file in *.mp4; do ffmpeg -i CONCAT COMMAND HERE; done
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks all!

Comment: Do you want intro.mp4 followed by all the files? Eg intro.mp4+1.mp4+2.mp4 ... or intro.mp4 + 1.mp4, and then a second file intro.mp4 + 2.mp4?

Comment: I have done with     @echo off
     
    mkdir output
    for %%i in (videos/*.mp4) do (
      echo file 'intro.mp4' > list.txt
      echo file 'videos/%%~nxi' >> list.txt
      ffmpeg -safe 0 -y -f concat -i list.txt -c copy "output/%%~nxi"
    )
    del list.txt
Thank You much for help!

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

`ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i filelist.txt -c copy output.mp4`

Details of [concatenate](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate) command can be found [here](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate).  The inputs need to be a file list other wise `ffmpeg` errors out with unknown keyword.

The `-safe 0` is not required if the file paths are relative.

So your bash script would look like:

```
#! /bin/bash
set -eou pipefail
NAME="file"
NEW="new-"
for file in *.mp4; 
do
    touch input.txt
    echo $NAME 'intro.mp4' >> filelist.txt
    echo $NAME $file  >> filelist.txt
    ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i filelist.txt -c copy $NEW$file;
    rm filelist.txt
done
```

The `filelist.txt` should look like:

```
file intro.mp4
file nextvideo.mp4
```

Comment: @OlegVolodchenko sorry the input needs to be a filelist - see new example

Comment: probably need to edit the /usr/local/bin/bash to /bin/bash - it's not creating the filelist.txt properly as the file is not been deleted between each call - it's removing a non existent input.txt - so the filelist.txt has extra junk that will mess it up.

Comment: it's not deleting the filelist.txt file between each go - but it's also not putting the word `file` into filelist.txt - each line should be `file nameof.mp4`

Comment: you could try changing the echo lines to `echo file intro.mp4 >> filelist.txt` and `echo file $file >> filelist.txt` but you will need to check if the resulting file looks like the example shown in the answer.

Comment: the error message unknown keyword '$NAME' means that for some reason `bash` is not replacing `$NAME` with the word `file`  in the  `filelist.txt` if you create a `filelist.txt` as shown in the answer and run the `ffmpeg` command from the command line does it work?